# Big commerce add active class using handlebar

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using the cornerstone theme and I need an active class for the current navigation. I have used the jQuery and javascript but I want to use the handlebars HTML template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to Handlebar. 
You can put {{is_active}} in navigation iteration loop in handlebar.

{{#if is_active}}active{{#if}}